# An overall PWM system by using FPGA

Tags: fpga, pwm, xilinx

I need to combine this 3 coding to form one whole PWM system by using FPGA. I  tried it, there is no error, but the process is not synthesizable. Please help me.
Thank you.

- This is code for FreqDivider200Hz

  ```
  library IEEE;
  use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
  use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

  entity FreqDivider200Hz is
  port(
  clock   : in STD_LOGIC; -- 50 Mhz
  clear   : in STD_LOGIC;
    freq1 : out STD_LOGIC
  );
  end FreqDivider200Hz;

  architecture Behavioral of FreqDivider200Hz is
  signal adjfreq: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(16 downto 0) := "00000000000000000";
  signal adjclock : std_logic := '0';

  begin

           freq1 <= adjclock;

  countClock: process(clock,clear)
  begin
  if (clear = '1') then
      adjfreq <= "00000000000000000";
  elsif(clock'event and clock = '1') then
      -- Flip a the output once every 125,000 cycles (400Hz)
      -- to give a 200Hz output with 50% duty cycle
      if (adjfreq = "11110100001001000") then  
          adjfreq <= "00000000000000000";
              if adjclock <= '0' then
              adjclock <= '1';
              else adjclock <= '0';
              end if;
          else 
          adjfreq <= adjfreq+1;   
      end if;
     end if;
    end process;
   end Behavioral;
  ```
- This is for code for FreqDivider400Hz

  ```
  enter library IEEE;
  use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
  use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

  entity FreqDivider400Hz is
  port(
  clock   : in STD_LOGIC; -- 50 Mhz
  clear   : in STD_LOGIC;
    freq2 : out STD_LOGIC
  );
  end FreqDivider400Hz;

  architecture Behavioral of FreqDivider400Hz is
  signal adjfreq: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0) := "0000000000000000";
  signal adjclock : std_logic := '0';

  begin

  freq2 <= adjclock;

  countClock: process(clock,clear)
  begin
  if (clear = '1') then
      adjfreq <= "0000000000000000";
  elsif(clock'event and clock = '1') then
      -- Flip a the output once every 62500 cycles
      -- to give a 400Hz output with 50% duty cycle
      if (adjfreq = "1111010000100100") then  
          adjfreq <= "0000000000000000";
              if adjclock <= '0' then
              adjclock <= '1';
              else adjclock <= '0';
              end if;
          else 
          adjfreq <= adjfreq+1;   
     end if;
    end if;
   end process;
  end Behavioral;code here
  ```
- This is code for 2x1 multiplexer

  ```
  library IEEE;
  use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
  use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
  use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

  ---- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
  ---- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
  --library UNISIM;
  --use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

  entity mux2to1 is
  Port ( freq1 : in  STD_LOGIC;
         freq2 : in  STD_LOGIC;
         sel : in  STD_LOGIC;
         y : out  STD_LOGIC);
  end mux2to1;

  architecture mux2to1 of mux2to1 is

  begin

  p1: process (freq1, freq2, sel)
  begin
  if sel = '0' then
          y <= freq1;
  else
          y <= freq2;
  end if;
  end process p1;
  End mux2to1;
  ```
- This is code for overall system

  ```
  library IEEE;
  use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
  use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
  use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

  entity OverallSystem is 
  Port ( clock : in STD_LOGIC; 
           clear : in STD_LOGIC; 
           sel : in STD_LOGIC; 
           y : out STD_LOGIC ); 
  end OverallSystem;

  architecture Behavioral of OverallSystem is
  component FreqDivider200Hz is
  port(
       clock   : in STD_LOGIC;
       clear   : in STD_LOGIC;
       freq1 : out STD_LOGIC);
  end component;

  component FreqDivider400Hz is
  port(
       clock   : in STD_LOGIC;
       clear   : in STD_LOGIC;
       freq2 : out STD_LOGIC);
  end component;

  component mux2to1 is
  Port ( freq1 : in  STD_LOGIC;
         freq2 : in  STD_LOGIC;
         sel : in  STD_LOGIC;
         y : out  STD_LOGIC);
  end component;

  signal freq1 : std_logic; 
  signal freq2 : std_logic;

  begin

  chip1 : mux2to1 port map ( freq1 => freq1, freq2 => freq2, sel => sel, y => y );
  chip2 : FreqDivider200Hz port map ( clock => clock, clear => clear, freq1 => freq1 );
  chip3 : FreqDivider400Hz port map ( clock => clock, clear => clear, freq2 => freq2 ); 

  end Behavioral;
  ```

Comment: PWM is just a timer and comparator. I would help better, but i am really not in a mood of code reading. You could ask a more clear question.

Comment: This is a Q&A site. So to write an answer we need a precise question from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See code below to combine 3 files together.

```
--- top.vhd

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity top is
port ( 
    clock : in  STD_LOGIC;
    clear : in  STD_LOGIC;
    sel   : in  STD_LOGIC;
    y     : out STD_LOGIC
);
end top;

architecture beh of top is

signal freq1 : std_logic;
signal freq2 : std_logic;

begin

chip1 : entity work.mux2to1
port map(
    freq1 => freq1,
    freq2 => freq2,
    sel   => sel  ,
    y     => y
);

chip2 : entity work.FreqDivider200Hz
port map( 
    clock => clock,
    clear => clear,
    freq1 => freq1
);

chip3 : entity work.FreqDivider400Hz
port map( 
    clock => clock,
    clear => clear,
    freq1 => freq2
);

end beh;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I already tried it, but it still have an error. This is the code.

Comment: I cannot see the error .... please attach the error line

Comment: How I can post my code here?

Comment: Just error line (copy/paste)

Comment: I added a little bit the code, there is no error. But for the process synthesis it shows this symbol !